# Does anyone recognize this monster family board game?

Tags: identify-this-game

I am gonna drive myself nuts because I can not remember the name of a board game from my childhood. It would have been between 1993–1999.

The box was shaped like a creepy castle or house and there was a laughing skull piece (like it's eyes glowed and it had this evil laugh). All your player pieces were tiny brightly colored skulls and the family of the house was all these monsters (granny mummy, Lord Skull?, a little girl vampire, I think a cousin or uncle was a werewolf) I think there was a rubber spider too. You had to go through the house (which may have been the box) and there was a goop soup monster. It Actually came with a book explaining how the soup monster was made.

It had the same humor of *The Addams Family* or *The Munsters* but was like a niche or indy game.

Comment: That's a hard one to find. This doesn't match everything you remember, but closest I could find is Horror House: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/17754/horror-house/images

Answer (score 7):

The game is called **[Creepy Towers](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/167495/creepy-towers)**.

- The box was shaped like a creepy castle or house and there was a
  laughing skull piece
- and you had to go through the house (which may
  have been the box)

[image]

From the publisher's description:

> Includes light-activated laughing skull

---

- and all your player pieces were tiny brightly colored skulls
- I think there was a rubber spider too…

[image]

From the publisher's description:

> Includes ... two rubber creatures

---

- It would have been between 1993-1999

The game was published in 1995

---

- Actually came with a book

From the publisher's description:

> as kids read Creepy Towers

And from the BoardGameGeek entry (linked above)

> Within Creepy Towers there is a board game, short story

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [*Which Witch?* / *Ghost Castle* / *Haunted House*](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1613/which-witch)? The player pieces aren't skulls but it does have a glowing skull that rolled down some stairs and knocked your piece over. And it has a set of cards with characters on them.

Answer (score 1):

The game is called "[Creepy Towers](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/167495/creepy-towers)".

Comment: Can you provide more information about this game and why you think it is a match?

Comment: @JoeW She's right though - loathe to add my own answer when this is correct https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/167495/creepy-towers

Comment: @MattThrower That wasn't a comment on the answer being right or wrong but the fact that the answer just contained the name of a game with no link or other information explaining why it is thought to be the correct game,

Comment: @joeW sure, I get that. I'm saying I'm not sure what to do in this situation  - post my own answer, edit this one, wait.

Comment: @MattThrower Do what you feel is best as this is at best a poor answer when it was posted since it just included a name and was later edited to at least include a link.

Comment: @MattThrower - Based on the general practices on english.SE: If you came up with the answer yourself, but then found that someone else had posted it but poorly explained/referenced it, then please go ahead and post your own good quality answer (especially if the first answerer has ignored requests to edit in explanation/research). If you didn't know the correct answer until you saw this one, please edit the research into this one.